# After company restructuring. how could I assert the type of role I want without risking redundancy?

Tags: manager, conflict, layoff, demotion

Question: I have already made it clear verbally what I want in my career and asked to speak
in a few weeks' time to discuss this. Apart from job hunting elsewhere, is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apart from job hunting elsewhere, is there anything else I can do?

Not really.

> Following a company restructure and furlough, I have been placed in the other department again.

This is important context - it sounds like your company has clearly been struggling financially because of recent events, and had to make redundancies / furlough staff in order to stay afloat. Bear in mind the situation hasn't really changed, so if it was struggling a few months back, chances are it still is. Your specialist knowledge is likely a large part of why you still have a job as you're clearly needed in the department you're currently in.

If it were me, I'd probably see the current company as a bit of a dead end in your career as its priority remains just staying afloat - and I'd probably advise moving on ASAP.